# Update Progress Bar automatically or from another form (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I have a progress bar on a form and some questions on another form. The user completes the questions and gets a score which is displayed as a percentage. I can make the progress bar update by using a button. However I would like the progress bar to update automatically when the form shows (swapping between forms with show and hide commands) or when a button is clicked on the other form. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Write some code to do just what you describe.  When you get stuck on something specific, *then* post a question.  [Ask]

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. The code itself for updating the progress bar works fine. All I needed to know was how to run it without having to press a button. I tried placing the code in the forms show event but it didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the two forms inside a module like this way

```
Module Questions
 Public WndForm1 as New Form1
 Public WndForm2 as New Form2

 Sub ShowQuestions()
   WndForm1.show()'//===>Here is where is your progress bar
   WndForm2.ShowDialog()'//===>Here is where you are going to update you progress bar
 End Sub
End Module
```

if you wan to update the progress in the wndForm2 you just need to do it  like this WndForm1.MyProgress.Value = 10